# Вопрос про python

Tags: python

У меня есть переменная "number" она пускай равна 33. Как мне сделать что бы она была равна     3,3. Что бы я как бы мог использовать функцию sum(), и вывело бы 6.

Comment: Непонятно зачем это всё, почему бы не сделать просто `print(6)`

Comment: `print(33 % 9)`

Comment: `sum(map(int, str(number)))`.

Answer (score 3):

`[int(c) for c in str(number)]` или `list(map(int, str(number)))` превращает число в список цифр:

> ```
> @>>> number = 33
> @>>> digits = list(map(int, str(number)))
> @>>> digits
> [3, 3]
> @>>> sum(digits)
> 6
> ```